# Running Sonar analysis through a service is resulting in an error, running in cmd prompt works fine

Tags: sonarqube, resharper, inspect

Running Sonar analysis through a service is resulting in this error, whereas when I login using the same user on same machine and running the same command works just fine and searching on that error also doesn't provide any details.

```
  <message>08:34:48.066 WARN  - ReSharper plugin is running in deprecated mode. inspectcode.exe should be ran outside the plugin and the report imported through sonar.resharper.cs.reportPath property.</message>
  <message>08:34:48.082 INFO  - Executing command: E:\Program Files\ResharperCommandLine\inspectcode.exe /output=E:\ccnet\server\AdAutomation\wd\.\.sonar\com.xyz.appdev_AdAutomation_ADAutomation.WebAPI\resharper-report.xml /no-swea /project=ADAutomation.WebAPI /profile=E:\ccnet\server\AdAutomation\wd\.\.sonar\com.xyz.appdev_AdAutomation_ADAutomation.WebAPI\resharper-sonarqube.DotSettings /no-buildin-settings E:\ccnet\server\AdAutomation\wd\.\ADAutomation.sln</message>
  <message>08:34:48.285 INFO  - InspectCode 8.1.23.523</message>
  <message>08:34:48.285 INFO  - Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 4.0.30319.34209 under Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - Internal exception thrown: Component CatalogType: JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Impl.Reflection2.ExternalAnnotations.ProductExternalAnnotationsFileProvider [Singleton, Corrupted] construction has failed. The component ProductExternalAnnotationsFileProvider constructor requires JetBrains.Application.Env.Components.ProductSettingsLocation, which we do not have.</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - </message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - --- EXCEPTION #1/3 [InvalidOperationException]</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - Message = "The component ProductExternalAnnotationsFileProvider constructor requires JetBrains.Application.Env.Components.ProductSettingsLocation, which we do not have."</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - ClassName = System.InvalidOperationException</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - Data.RejectedConstructors.#0.Signature = "Void .ctor(JetBrains.Application.Env.Components.ProductSettingsLocation)"</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - Data.RejectedConstructors.#0.UnsatisfiedTypes.#0 = "JetBrains.Application.Env.Components.ProductSettingsLocation, JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.Shell, Version=8.1.23.523, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325"</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - Data.DescriptorType = "JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor, JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.ComponentModel, Version=8.1.23.523, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325"</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - Data.State = Null</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - Source = JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.ComponentModel</message>
  <message>08:34:50.191 INFO  - StackTraceString = "</message>
```

So far I have tried to update resharper command line tools but still no luck.
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Does your service user have permissions/access to the R# tools?

Comment: Thank Ann for replying......
Nothing related to permisson/access because when I execute the above sonar or inspectcode command with the same service account on same machine runs fine.